# how to properly set the size of a lightbox on a mobile web page

Tags: jquery, mobile

I want to show a lightbox style div on the mobile website.

1.The resolution of my android phone is 1920×1080
2.$(window).width() returns 980,$(window).height() returns 1543 on my website.
3.I set the size of the lightbox is to 800px*600px
4.I set the < meta name="viewport" content="device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />

However, the lightbox can't be fully displayed on my android phone.

Can anyone provide some advices?

Answer (score 0):

```
content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"
```